# Celery How to make a worker run only when other workers are broken?

Tags: python, celery

I have two servers, there is one celery worker on each server. I use Redis as the broker to collaborate with workers.

My question is how can I make only one worker run for most of the time, and once this worker is broken, another worker will turn on as a backup worker?

Basically, just take one worker as a back-up.

I know how to specify a task to a certain worker by a queue on the worker respectively, after reading the doc [http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#redis-message-priorities]

Comment: This is not a programming question since is unrelated to the code running on the worker. You should ask in one of our server or system management related sibling sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is, in my humble opinion, completely against the point of having distributed system to off-load CPU heavy, or long-running tasks, or have thousands of small tasks that you can't run elsewhere...

- You are running two servers anyway, so why keeping the other one idle? More workers mean you will be able to process more tasks concurrently.

If you are not convinced, and still want to do this, you need to write a tiny service on machine with idle Celery worker. This service will periodically check the health of the active worker, and if that check fails, you will run Celery worker on the backup server.

Here is a question for you - why this service simply does not restart the Celery worker on the active server? - It is pretty much possible to do that, so again, I see no justification for having a completely idle machine doing nothing. If you are on a cloud platform, you can easily spin up a new instance from an existing image of your Celery worker. This is scenario I use in production.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing. I'm using cloud ECS. the backup server is of low configuration, so I just keep it idle as a sheer backup. In my scenario, while the main worker is restarting or being broken, the backup could subtitute. I think I'm more to write a tiny service as you said.